# Getting the message "Error writing file" from mega.co.nz

Tags: mega

I am recently downloading a movie from [MEGA](https://mega.co.nz/) and I suddenly get following error message:

`Error writing file, is your harddrive almost full? (getFile)`

Now maybe it's because of my lack of knowledge but what exactly does it want from me?
In the File Manager I used 2GB out of 50GB and on my Laptop I still have over 20GB space.

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe it's cache can't take the file.

Answer (score 1):

I issued the same problem, and it was resolved by itself connecting my account and refreshing the web browser (chrome in my case), the downloading starts then and everything is alright, hope this will be fine for you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete cookies for mega in your browser. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means you lack space in drive C:\ (or where your browser is installed) on your computer.
If you have other drives with more space then you must download the Mega application to be able to set a different download location.